# Google Script openByID give Exception

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I met with strange problem. I have one table and this little code:

```
function myFunction() {
  static_sheetID = "***********************"
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(static_sheetID)  
}
```

And it returns this error:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with
> id *************.
> myFunction  @ test.gs:6

So, how can I resolve this problem?
Yes. The table is really **HEAVY**.
I need to copy some data from it.
It might be working if I will do it with:
`Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(id, range)`
But not sure, and don't want to rewrite code due to this error.
It appears only in one table.

Comment: Looks like a glitch exactly because the heaviness. I'd consider `try/catch` for this little code.

Comment: I tried it literally 5 minutes ago. Using a loop with try{}catch{} until true.
But it gives nothing:/ And I turned off script on 300~ cycle.
Does GoogleScriptApi have function, which will be connect to table, but not open it or smth?

Comment: This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/156530211) seems to be already known and investigated. It seems that apart from handling the error, [disabling v8](https://issuetracker.google.com/182053596) helps some users. But if you could reduce the heaviness of your spreadsheet that would be the easiest solution.

Comment: I can't disable v8, because true script is **more harder** than example. 
And there are a lot of errors appear, if I refuse V8.
Also! the `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(id, range)` does not work too.
I will try ask to reduce table weight, it seems like only decision=(((

Comment: But sometimes it's work!   
I need to be 100% sure that the script will work.  
What does it depend on?